# ORACLE How to get data from a table depending on year and the amount of duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

so the question is "Produce a list of those employees who have made bookings at the Sports  Club more than 5 times in the last calendar year (this should be calculated and not hard coded).  Order these by the number of bookings made."

what i am struggling with is being able to get todays year and then subtract 1 year aswell as showing ONLY one name of people appearing 5 times. 
this is what i have so far, but it doesnt work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
FIRSTNAME,SURNAME,DATEBOOKED,MEMBERSHIPTYPEID,BOOKINGID,MEMBER.MEMBERID
FROM MEMBERSHIP,MEMBER,BOOKING
WHERE MEMBER.MEMBERID = BOOKING.MEMBERID
AND MEMBERSHIP.MEMBERSHIPTYPEID = 3 AND BOOKING.DATEBOOKED = (SYSDATE, 
'DD/MON/YY -1') AND FIRSTNAME IN (
SELECT FIRSTNAME
FROM MEMBER
GROUP BY FIRSTNAME,SURNAME
HAVING COUNT(FIRSTNAME) >= 5
)
ORDER BY MEMBER.MEMBERID;
```

[EDR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7AU7.png)

[tabele structures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SqmD.png)

Comment: Use ANSI join syntax rather than implicit join with commas. If you've used the required columns in `GROUP BY` , `DISTINCT` is superfluous. So, show us the *sample data* and *expected o/p*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is this day last year. There are various different ways of calculating that. For instance,

```
add_months(sysdate, -12)
```

or

```
sysdate - interval '1' year
```

The subquery looks a bit whacky too. What you're after is the number of BOOKING records in the last year. So the subquery should drive off the BOOKING table, and the date filter should be there.

Finally, there is a missing join condition between  MEMBER and MEMBERSHIP. That's probably why you think you need that `distinct`; fix the join and you'll get the result set you want and not a product. One advantage of the ANSI 92 explicit join syntax is that it stops us from missing joins.

Your query needs to be sorted by the number of bookings, so you need to count those and sort by the total. This means you don't actually need a subquery at all.

So your query should look something like:

```
SELECT MEMBER.MEMBERID
        , MEMBER.FIRSTNAME
        , MEMBER.SURNAME
        , count(BOOKING.BOOKID) as no_of_bookings
FROM MEMBER 
     inner join MEMBERSHIP
     on MEMBER.MEMBERID = MEMBERSHIP.MEMBERID
     inner join BOOKING
     on MEMBER.MEMBERID = BOOKING.MEMBERID 
WHERE MEMBERSHIP.MEMBERSHIPTYPEID = 3
and BOOKING.DATEBOOKED >= add_months(trunc(sysdate), -12) 
GROUP BY MEMBER.MEMBERID
        , MEMBER.FIRSTNAME
        , MEMBER.SURNAME
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
ORDER BY no_of_bookings desc;
```

Here is [a SQL Fiddle demo for my query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e7a510/1).

Comment: your code throws error at line 5 saying invalid identifier. and yes i agree i have no idea what i was doing inside the subquery. first time working with sql

Comment: You didn't post the actual table structures so I had to guess what other columns you have and how the tables are related. I have made another guess. If this is wrong then please pay us the courtesy of **editing your question** to include the pertinent table structures.

Comment: added table structure link

Comment: also added edr for clarification

Comment: Okay, so having seen your ERD my previous version was right, and the join between MEMBER and MEMBERSHIP *is* on MEMBERID. So I have reverted the query.

Comment: this works, however it shows people that have made any booking in 2017 and then counts all of their bookings in any date. The question asks for it to only display the amount of bookings made in last year and order by the number of bookings in that last year.

Comment: Hmmmm. I have created [a SQL Fiddle and my query returns the expected members with the expected booking counts](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e7a510/1). So if you're getting different results it will be due to some difference you have introduced in translating my code into your environment.

Comment: Your sql fiddle only contains data with dates ranging in 2017 - 2018. the sql is supposed to count the bookings made in that year only. so if mr fox has made 2 bookings in 2017 and 1 booking in 2015. the result should be 2. thanks again for your help you have really helped me allot.

Comment: Your requirements say you want people who appear **five times** which I have interpreted to mean *people who at least five bookings in the last twelve months*. So if Fox had the bookings you suggest he wouldn't appear at all. You seem a bit confused by your own requirements and frankly I have already spent way too much of my time on this question. I have shown you the necessary SQL techniques to solve the problem. You need to apply them to whatever data you have to get the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
FIRSTNAME,SURNAME,DATEBOOKED,MEMBERSHIPTYPEID,BOOKINGID,MEMBER.MEMBERID
FROM MEMBERSHIP,MEMBER,BOOKING
WHERE MEMBER.MEMBERID = BOOKING.MEMBERID
AND MEMBERSHIP.MEMBERSHIPTYPEID = 3 AND BOOKING.DATEBOOKED between (SYSDATE) and  
(sysdate - interval '1' year) 
AND FIRSTNAME IN (
SELECT distinct FIRSTNAME
FROM MEMBER
GROUP BY FIRSTNAME,SURNAME
HAVING COUNT(FIRSTNAME) >= 5
)
ORDER BY MEMBER.MEMBERID;
```

Comment: This query will return zero records because the arguments of `BETWEEN()` must be `(lower bound, higher bound)`

Answer (score 0):

I think this answers the question:

```
SELECT m.FIRSTNAME, m.SURNAME, m.MEMBERID
FROM MEMBER m JOIN
     BOOKING b
     ON m.MEMBERID = b.MEMBERID JOIN
     MEMBERSHIP ms
     ON ms.MEMBERID = m.MEMBERID
WHERE ms.MEMBERSHIPTYPEID = 3 AND
      B.DATEBOOKED >= SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1 YEAR'
GROUP BY  m.FIRSTNAME, m.SURNAME, m.MEMBERID
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
ORDER BY COUNT(* DESC;
```

Table aliases make the query much easier to write and to read.

Comment: hmm, for some reason it displays members that have made a booking 3 times, or 2. and only some are 5